# Create an html formatted report

Tags: python, html, reporting

I have a Python 2.6 app running on Linux that creates a CSV file. From the app, I need to create an HTML report, as a single HTML file, that presents the data from the CSV (probably as a table) and also highlights fields where the values meet certain criteria. Charting type functionality would be a nice to have.

What's the best way to do this?

No GPL stuff please.

Comment: Pretty clear I thought. I don't want to use a library that is covered by the GPL.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem anything to do with programming.

Comment: @SilentGhost: tfi might be that he doesn't want the code he writes to be GPL'd.

Comment: You could use Python's built-in `csv` module and generate your own HTML using `print` statements or file `write()` methods (HTML, and HTML tables aren't hard). No licensing issues with this approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose a Python csv library from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=csv&submit=search). Now that you have the data mapped to Python data structures you can iterate on it and create the html. I would use the [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) templating engine which is nicely documented. Highlighting rows/cells would work by setting certain css classes on the respective tr/td elements in the table.

Comment: Regarding charts: my pick would be the Google Charts API (https://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/) which - for a given set of data - returns an image with a chart. There's a very nice Python wrapper lib for it here: http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/ . From the example code I find it very easy to use: https://github.com/gak/pygooglechart/blob/master/examples/pie.py

Comment: why is there a need to choose a csv library from *there*, is there something wrong with the stdlib module?

Comment: @SilentGhost to be honest, I wasn't aware of such a module. That's of course the best choice, if @VacuumTube has a Python version with this built-in. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @chris: FYI the `csv` module was added in version 2.3. Check out the [Global Module Index](http://docs.python.org/modindex.html), there's lots of goodies there, all released under the Python Software Foundation License Version 2.

Comment: @martineau thanks for the link. "Batteries included" indeed :)